# How to scroll to a position after the DOM is loaded using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 100);
});
```

Unfortunately, it seems like the scroll is being ignored by the browsers, ie, the browser sets whatever position that was there before the reload. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try and delay the scroll by using setTimeout with a delay of 1?

Comment: use setTimeOut() for delay it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 100);
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: I think you could even just wait for 0ms cz that means it waits for one “tick“

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 100);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello World </h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can add 0 sec timing don't need to wait longer

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {window.scrollTo(0, 100);}, 0);
});
```